# Почему в Qt нет ни QtWebView ни QtWebEngine?

Tags: qt, qtcreator

У меня установлена Qt версия 5.8. Пытаюсь компилировать QtWebView или QtWebEngine, но такое впечатление, что они не установлены. Как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что его нужно доустановить - по умолчанию он не ставится. Запускаете "Qt Maintenance Tool"  (он обычно находиться в `C:\Qt\`), выбираете "Add or remove components" next  и потом в большом дереве выбираете нужное.

Comment: К сожалению, выдаёт ошибку: "At least one valid and enabled repository for this action to succed"

Comment: странно. Но похоже вот ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775906/how-to-update-component-in-qt-5-2-1

Comment: не помогло... возможно, нужно переустановить Qt?

Comment: все может быть. У меня подобных проблем не возникало.

Comment: А какой вы компилятор используете?

Comment: на данный момент я в основном использую компилятор от 2015 студии и Qt 5.6.2. Но бывает и компилятор от 2013 студии. Правда, думаю, это не имеет отношения к вопросу.

Comment: @KoVadim имеет, на версии 5.8 QtWebEngine на компиляторе minGW не поддерживается.